# What is Hue all about?

Tags: hadoop, hue

I am new to Big Data. I want to know about Hue. All i know about Hue is that it is a web interface to manage Hadoop ecosystem. Please let me know if i can install in on my pc (Ubuntu Precise). I am running Apache Hadoop 1.2.1 in pseudo distributed mode with PIG and HIVE

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Hue is a Web interface for analyzing data with Apache Hadoop. You can install it in any pc with any hadoop version.

Hue is a suite of applications that provide web-based access to CDH components and a platform for building custom applications.

The following figure illustrates how Hue works. Hue Server is a "container" web application that sits in between your CDH installation and the browser. It hosts the Hue applications and communicates with various servers that interface with CDH components.

[image]

here you have all the explanations about hue and downloads:

http://gethue.com/

Comment: As for today, I can't find this in the official docs, may it should be added there!